# What is a good SQUID Logs Analyzer?

Tags: proxy, squid, log-files, http-proxy, logparser

Can anyone recommend me a good tool for analyzing squid logs ?

I'm currently using **[SARG](http://sarg.sourceforge.net/)**. Is there something better? 
I need to easily see what sites were visited/denied, when and by whom.

There is a list of squid analyzers. Some of them seem to be out of date.

**[Squid: Logfile Analysis](http://www.squid-cache.org/Scripts/)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I used LightSquid: http://lightsquid.sourceforge.net/ 
It was good enough for me for several reasons:

- It is fast, takes very little diskspace (In comparison with SARG, only ~45Kb of Perl scripts)
- There is nothing superfluous

You can try it, using online-demo:
http://lightsquid.sourceforge.net/demo17/index.cgi?year=2005&month=04

"Official" feauture-list:

- fast and simple install fast log
- parser generatesmall per user data
- file perl based cgi script for
- dynamic generated report pages html
- template for design no database
- required no additional perl module
- various reports user groups support
- graphics report (v 1.6+) real name
- (v 1.6+) multilangual interface

Comment: Is it still active? No update on website nor sourcecode since 2009.

Comment: Seems like the project is frozen since then.

Answer (score 3):

[Calamaris](http://cord.de/tools/squid/calamaris/) might provide what you're looking for.  Handles many different types of logs, including squid.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Free-SA](http://free-sa.sourceforge.net) which is similar to SARG but much faster and doesn't crash on huge log files. It works very well.

> "Free-SA is statistic analyzer for daemons log files similar to SARG. Its main advantages over SARG are much better speed (7x-20x times), more reports support, crossplatform work and W3C compliance of generated HTML/CSS reports code."

Comment: I have managed to install this, and it looks great. Do you have any links to help on setting up cron tasks for it?

Answer (score 0):

I use sarg, but for personal use i use sqview (http://github.com/mezgani/sqview/tree/master), and sometimes awk scripting that is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a security log analyzer, you will like [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net). It monitors the logs looking for multiple 404s, 500s, worm actions, etc. Great to detect internal compromises.